# Stylus: How can I change the color on an element when it has an additional class?

Tags: css, colors, stylus

We're using icomoon so that our icons are fonts and we can change their color easily. But, I'm having a problem styling an icon so that the default color is `lightgrey` and, when  it has a `primary` class its color is `yelloworange`. Right now, my stylesheet looks like this:

```
i
  &.icon-star.primary
    color yelloworange
  &.icon-star
    color lightgrey
```

## Each of these styles works on their own.

But, when I have both of them, all of the icons are `lightgrey` and the icons with the `primary` class are not `yelloworange`. (I've checked the elements and they do have the correct class names).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: well, the obvious answer is to reverse the cascade and if anything add !important

Comment: @Fabio: `.icon-star.primary` is more specific than `.icon-star`, so order shouldn’t matter. (And `!important` isn’t really a fix.)

Comment: @Fabio, I thought the same thing but reversing them didn't have any effect. I've got a quick and dirty solution using another class for the `lightgrey` style but I'm curious to see if there's any way to do it with just the `primary` tag.

Comment: This feels off... is that sass syntax? Could you post what the sass compiles to in css? I think that may be where the answer lies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround that I've figured out is to use a `standard` class for `lightgrey` stars and `primary` class for `yelloworange` stars. It doesn't seem as elegant as only adding one class to the primary stars but it does work.

```
    i
      &.icon-star.primary
        color yelloworange
      &.icon-star.standard
        color lightgrey
```

Answer (score 12):

> Each of these styles works on their own.

I doubt it, since `yelloworange` [isn’t a CSS colour](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#named-colors). If you look at Stylus’s rendered CSS, you’ll see that it doesn’t recognize the colour either (Stylus would have transformed it to its hex representation).

If you did have `yelloworange` defined as a custom value, make sure you still do!

Comment: he's defining color names via CSS pre-processors

Comment: @Fabio: Is that mentioned somewhere in the question?

Comment: no, but it's obvious. Anyways, just mentioning why he can be right with that code, I'm not that jumpy. And now I see your other comment so I can see you're in a roll, have fun, I'm out.

Comment: @Fabio Still that should've been either added in the question or at least a tag should've been added. The "im out" additude isn't helping your statement either. But lets keep this away from meta.

Comment: @spinlock, instead of flagging my answer, perhaps you could try it and give feedback.

Comment: @minitech this is not an answer to the question I asked. It is just distracting from the actual issue and I don't feel like getting into a flame war. If you're only going to be argumentative rather than answer the questions the people actually ask, you should expect your posts to be flagged. I'm just disappointed that your post hasn't been removed. You've already driven off the only other commenter who was interested in answering the question that was asked and I'm sure others will want to stay away from the drama.

Comment: @spinlock: I’m answering the question. If it doesn’t work for you, you could say so (you still haven’t). If you’ve defined `yelloworange`, please note that in the question, and provide a minimum amount of code we can use to reproduce the issue. I’m not sure where anyone’s getting the impression that I’m being argumentative; Fabio appears to have been driven off by me pointing out that the fix suggested in his comment shouldn’t make a difference (which you’ve confirmed), and that’s hardly my fault. If you’re not interested in getting help, I can always leave too.